# How can I embed a Universal Subtitles video on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, video, subtitles

I have created English subtitles for a video on [Universal Subtitles](http://www.universalsubtitles.org/) and now I want to embed it in my Tumblr blog.  I tried copying the embed code provided but on Tumblr that just comes out as the plain YouTube video, without the extra Universal Subtitles GUI (and without subtitles).

This is the embed code provided, in case it helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.www.universalsubtitles.org/embed.js">
(
  {"video_url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8f0AUkFw6s"}
)
</script>
```

Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do it without fixing your theme.

Inserting raw javascript HTML code from another domain is known security risk and normally is not available (prevented) in post editor on "post save" operation at site like Tumblr.

You ought to start with reading [Tumblr's theme ustomize manual](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) and unless you feel ready and sure you won't break it, don't mess with themes hard.